# Javascript JSON - Convert items to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a javascript object converted using stringify that looks like this..

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(response);

{"0":{"trigger":17},"1":{"trigger":3},"2":{"trigger":40},"3":{"trigger":4},"4":{"trigger":19},"5":{"trigger":70},"6":{"trigger":80},"7":{"trigger":0},"8":{"trigger":0},"9":{"trigger":5},"10":{"trigger":4}}
```

I am trying to create an array but only of the value of trigger.

Should I loop through the response and do it that way or is there a better way like map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` method on `Object.values`.

```js
const json = {"0":{"trigger":17},"1":{"trigger":3},"2":{"trigger":40},"3":{"trigger":4},"4":{"trigger":19},"5":{"trigger":70},"6":{"trigger":80},"7":{"trigger":0},"8":{"trigger":0},"9":{"trigger":5},"10":{"trigger":4}}

const arr = Object.values(json).map(({trigger}) => trigger);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seemed like the most straightforward method.  Works great

Answer (score 3):

You may get all the values from the object using `Object.values` and then apply `Array.map` on the collection to get the values of `trigger` only:

```js
const obj = {"0":{"trigger":17},"1":{"trigger":3},"2":{"trigger":40},"3":{"trigger":4},"4":{"trigger":19},"5":{"trigger":70},"6":{"trigger":80},"7":{"trigger":0},"8":{"trigger":0},"9":{"trigger":5},"10":{"trigger":4}};

const arr = Object.values(obj).map(item => item.trigger);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `for..in` to iterate over the object and push the value to `trigger` to another array

```js
let data = {
  "0": {
    "trigger": 17
  },
  "1": {
    "trigger": 3
  },
  "2": {
    "trigger": 40
  },
  "3": {
    "trigger": 4
  },
  "4": {
    "trigger": 19
  },
  "5": {
    "trigger": 70
  },
  "6": {
    "trigger": 80
  },
  "7": {
    "trigger": 0
  },
  "8": {
    "trigger": 0
  },
  "9": {
    "trigger": 5
  },
  "10": {
    "trigger": 4
  }
}
let arrVal = [];

for (var keys in data) {

  arrVal.push(data[keys].trigger)
};
console.log(arrVal)
```